# How to use custom analyzer in ElasticSearch?

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-plugin

I wanted to try Elasticsearch with Polish language support, but I have some problems with it. 
I installed [Stempel Analysis Plugin](https://github.com/elasticsearch/elasticsearch-analysis-stempel), I'm trying to create an index that uses Polish analyzer:

```
curl -XPUT localhost:9200/polisz -d '{ 
 "mappings" : {
  "_default_" : {
   "properties" : {
    "text_entry" : { "type": "string", "analyzer": "polish" }
   }
  }
 }
}
'
```

But I get an error about not recognized analyzer:

```
{
   "status" : 400,
   "error" : "MapperParsingException[mapping [_default_]]; nested: MapperParsingException[Analyzer [polish] not found for field [text_entry]]; "
}
```

Should I do anything after installing the plugin and rebooting ES? 
I can't find any specific instructions about using the plugin so maybe I'm just doing something obviously wrong?

Some more details on how I set up my environment:
I installed and run docker image with ES and kibana by commands:

```
docker pull minimum2scp/es-kibana
docker run -d -p 8080:80 -p 9200:9200 --name es minimum2scp/es-kibana
```

I installed the Stempel plugin by command:

```
host$ docker exec -it es bash
root@docker-es:/# /usr/share/elasticsearch/bin/plugin install elasticsearch/elasticsearch-analysis-stempel/2.4.2
```

Then I rebooted elasticsearch, by:
    root@docker-es:/# service elasticsearch restart

I'll be grateful for any help!
Krzysztof

Comment: Could you run the following?
curl localhost:9200/_cat/plugins?v

Comment: I already solved the problem, but your advice would have helped me finding out, that plugin didn't install correctly. So Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

OK, I got it. It seems that my **plugin didn't install correctly**. Even that plugin install command doesn't return any errors, neither elasticsearch restart command, there was a **Lucene version mismatch**  in  Elasticsearch( I don't remember, but below 4.10.2) and the plugin (4.10.3).

It was enough to look into elasticsearch.log file to find it out...My bad.

BUT there is more to it: I switched to the most popular (by stars) elasticsearch docker image, which is: dockerfile/elasticsearch. It has the ES version 1.4.2 that is based on Lucene 4.10.2, still mismatching the plugin Lucene 4.10.3. That causes an error even though authors of plugin states it plugin in 2.4.2 (current stable) support 1.4 ES version(s). 
Citing an error for future web searching the problem:

```
[2015-02-13 10:57:11,850][INFO ][node                     ] [Necromantra] version[1.4.2], pid[1], build[927caff/2014-12-16T14:11:12Z]
[2015-02-13 10:57:11,851][INFO ][node                     ] [Necromantra] initializing ...                                                       
[2015-02-13 10:57:11,884][ERROR][plugins                  ] [Necromantra] cannot start plugin due to incorrect Lucene version: plugin [4.10.3], node [4.10.2].
[2015-02-13 10:57:11,884][WARN ][plugins                  ] [Necromantra] failed to load plugin from [jar:file:/data/plugins/analysis-stempel/elasticsearch-analysi
s-stempel-2.4.2.jar!/es-plugin.properties]
```

Now I chose a path to downgrade the plugin to 2.4.1, which agreed with my ES 1.4.2. Although in the long term I would look for docker image that has 1.4.3 ES which, hopefully,upgraded Lucene version as well.

[Dadoonet](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1432281/dadoonet), thank you for having a closer look on my problem.

Comment: Yeah. I agree. Documentation fixed.